# PS3 Eyetoy video camera not working in Skype

Tags: 11.04, video, hardware

As it says,

- tested the Eyetoy with windows (on laptop) works fine
- tested with Cheese, works fine
- tested with Empathy, talkiong to MSN Messenger, also fine!!

Skype? GRRR    Black screen...   Has anybody found a workaround please?

Comment: Install an older version fo Skype

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the drivers used by your computer to help it recognize the webcam were not intended to be used with skype. Carefully check through your Skype preferences, and be sure everything is as should be, if the problem is still there, reinstall Skype. 
Sorry I couldn't give much info, hope it helps though. :)